# mysql shrink where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 10 columns and 24 rows that can store a value or can be = 0. They are called msg1, msg2... up to msg10.
I am writing a query to update this table with 0 instead of a specific value in any of the fields.

So I wrote (59 is a test value and will be dinamically updated by php):

```
UPDATE schedule SET msg1='0' WHERE msg1='59' OR SET msg2='0' WHERE msg2='59'....
OR SET msg10='0' WHERE msg10='59'
```

This is obviously not working and anyway would be one of the less efficient query I have ever seen. So the question is: what is a clever way of iterating through all the rows and the columns, look for the specific value (i.e. 59) and if yes change it to 0?

I know that i can do it using a for loop but this will end up doing each time 24 query... not efficient too!

Comment: `This is obviously not working and anyway would be one of the less efficient query` , if query is not working , how come you know if its less efficient in terms of time ?

Comment: look into using "case", its quite handy...  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Comment: See normalisation. See normalisation. See normalisation.

Comment: @dbinns66 case is a good idea but i was looking for something like spencer's answer

Comment: @Strawberry this table has 24 rows (one for each hour of the day) and 10 columns (one for each group of users) and is used for planning what each group will do on each hour. If you have an idea on how to apply normalization on this table you are welcome! I have no clue to write something better ;)

Comment: Ugh, it gets worse!!! A database table is not a spreadhseet. Just store data, i.e. what someone is doing and when. So that's a column for a user, a column for a start datetime (and possibly a column for an end datetime), and a column for an activity. So four columns max.  If you don't know something, don't store it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have to reference each column.  I'd just do a full scan of the table, and update every row. An index isn't going to help, no need for a `WHERE` clause. Assuming those columns are character, use single quotes around the values. If those are numeric, you can omit the single quotes.

```
UPDATE schedule
   SET msg1 = IF(msg1='59','0',msg1)
     , msg2 = IF(msg2='59','0',msg2) 
     , msg3 = IF(msg3='59','0',msg3) 
     , ...
```

---

If you want to add a `WHERE` clause (which isn't really needed), you'd add it after the `SET` clause...

```
WHERE msg1='59'
   OR msg2='59'
   OR msg3='59'
```

---

I'd be tempted to write the statement so I only had to specify the value `'59'` and `'0'` just one time, like this:

```
UPDATE schedule s
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT '59' AS oldval, '0' AS newval) v
   SET s.msg1 = IF(s.msg1=v.oldval,v.newval,s.msg1)
     , s.msg2 = IF(s.msg2=v.oldval,v.newval,s.msg2)
     , s.msg3 = IF(s.msg3=v.oldval,v.newval,s.msg3)
```

Comment: Your third example is really interesting. Since I need to replace '59' with a php variable it is very handy. Never used CROSS JOIN, thanks! I've learned something new!

Comment: @LelioFaieta: NOTE: With literals in the SELECT list in an inline view, we can run into issues with implicit characterset conversions throwing  "not coercible" error, for example, if client characterset is utf8 and the table column we're comparing to is latin1.) (That inline view is getting materialized as a  "derived table", so the columns get a characterset. If you run into that issue, there's ways to workaround that...   `SELECT _latin1'59'`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. This time I am lucky since this is a web app for some devices to be installed in some rooms of a facility. So I have full control on both server and clients ;)